# Prestashop: array from smarty to JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, smarty, prestashop

I need to build table with features in JS and display it on .tpl.
I want to transfer array from smarty to JS. At first, i try with variable:

```
{literal}<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"> 
<!-- // variable="{/literal}{$product->name|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}{literal}"; 
// --> </script>{/literal}
```

and it work's. Than i try with array:

```
{literal}<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"> 
<!-- // array="{/literal}{$features|json_encode}{literal}"; 
// --> </script>{/literal}
```

and this solution is not working. Do you have any ideas how can I build array in JS from array in smarty?

Answer (score 1):

Taken from usage in other tpl in Prestashop, you can do it this way:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    taxesArray = new Array();
    {foreach $taxesRatesByGroup as $tax_by_group}
        taxesArray[{$tax_by_group.id_tax_rules_group}] = {$tax_by_group|json_encode};
    {/foreach}
</script>
```

or for the features example you gave, should be something like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    featuresArray = new Array();
    {foreach $features key=k item=f}
        featuresArray[{$k}] = {$f|json_encode};
    {/foreach}
</script>
```